# typescript webcomponent creation question

Tags: typescript, class, web-component, extends

I have this classes:

```
class BaseComponent extends HTMLElement {
genericMethod1();
genericMethod2();
genericMethod3();
}

class MyComponentTextArea extends HTMLTextAreaElement {
    [dynamicProperty: string]: any;
}

class MyComponentInput extends HTMLInputElement {
    [dynamicProperty: string]: any;
}
```

in run time: copy BaseComponent -> MyComponentTextArea or BaseComponent -> MyComponentInput for not duplicate all generic methods.

const obj = new MyComponentTextArea();
obj.genericMethod1(); // work, but...

I have searched a lot, but I can't find a good solution

like

```
type classelement<T extends HTMLElement> = T;

class BaseComponent<T extends HTMLElement> extends classelement<T> {
genericMethod1();
genericMethod2();
genericMethod3();
}

class MyComponentTextArea extends BaseComponent<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
}

class MyComponentInput extends BaseComponent<HTMLInputElement> {
}
```

therer are any posibility???

thanks.

Comment: FYI, extending Built-In Elements won't work in Safari. HTMLElement is all you can extend. Apple stills refuses to implement this part of the standard.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. but anyway I think it's good question for other problems.